# Executing different types of browsers in parallel in Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium-grid

I have one test cases which I want to execute on same machine with different types of browsers like IE,FF,Chrome,Safari.

The problem is that I am able to launch all 4 types of browsers, but could not complete executing them fully.

For example, my test case gets executed completely only in IE, not in Safari,Chrome,FF..

Do I need to implement any Thread.Sleep statements between each step so that all my test steps execute in all 4 types of browsers?

Comment: Can you please share some code to show how you are launching the browsers/ calling tests in parallel?

Comment: Thread.Sleep doesn't make the steps to run in parallel..

Answer (score 0):

Running browsers in parallel one machine doesn't quite work well. I've tried it many times, and they conflict each other, sometimes making tests fail...What I did was use a VM per browser, but that's costly.